# Can we use the prolog in XML in capital?

Tags: xml

I know that XML is case sensitive and when I wrote the prolog in capital it showed error but I want to make sure that I hit the right spot or I am wrong.

Comment: Where did you look to find this information before asking here? Please don't use this site just because it's quicker than looking things up in the documentation.

Comment: Hello  I didn't intend that but I di wanted to ask from the world's best people in it since I am just a beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names in the XML declaration ("xml", "version", "encoding", "standalone") must be in lower-case.